# How did Baahubali move very fast right after bulls with fire horns run?

Tags: character, baahubali-2-the-conclusion

In *Baahubali 2 (2017)*, int the scene after the bulls with fire horns run is over, soldiers are coming forward and try to attack Devasena. Then Baahubali moved very fast like Flash in DC Comics. How did he move very fast right after fire bulls run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scene was intended to show the skill of Baahubali in warfare and how Baahubali could outmatch the speed of soldiers' of Kuntala kingdom in war. He was very fast in fighting war. This leaves Devasena in astonishment. To depict this, the director and the cinematographer chose to show Baahubali like a lightning speed. When someone moves very fast, it is said that he/she moved like a flash or lightning. Here too, Baahubali moved very quickly than other soldiers. Before other soldiers could react, Baahubali started killing the opponent soldiers. A glimpse of  extensive training undergone by Baahubali is shown in a [song](https://youtu.be/12fcHpwLKl4?t=145) in *Baahubali : The Beginning* where he single handedly faces hundreds of arrows from all the directions using his sword.

So, this scene is intended to show Baahubali's swiftness in war compared to others.

Answer (score 1):

Because He is Baahubali. He was trained in all the skills from his childhood. He knows everything in warfare and his entire family has superpowers. Even his cousin brother can kill a big Bison in one punch.